# Package Installer crashes when installing certain apps (`java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not copy bitmap to parcel blob.`)

Tags: applications, crashes

This issue started a few weeks ago on my Google Pixel 6 running Android 14, it only happens with certain apps but the issue is the same for all of them, the "Package Installer" crashes after tapping Install.

Here's a full stacktrace that I dumped from syslog:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.google.android.packageinstaller, PID: 3209
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not copy bitmap to parcel blob.
 at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeWriteToParcel(Native Method)
 at android.graphics.Bitmap.writeToParcel(Bitmap.java:2271)
 at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:2584)
 at com.android.packageinstaller.PackageUtil$AppSnippet.writeToParcel(PackageUtil.java:151)
 at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:2584)
 at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:2485)
 at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:2362)
 at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:1298)
 at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1843)
 at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1389)
 at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:1367)
 at android.content.Intent.writeToParcel(Intent.java:11807)
 at android.os.Parcel.writeTypedObject(Parcel.java:2203)
 at android.app.IActivityTaskManager$Stub$Proxy.startActivity(IActivityTaskManager.java:2077)
 at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1873)
 at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5615)
 at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5573)
 at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:6071)
 at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:6038)
 at com.android.packageinstaller.PackageInstallerActivity.startInstall(PackageInstallerActivity.java:701)
 at com.android.packageinstaller.PackageInstallerActivity.lambda$bindUi$0(PackageInstallerActivity.java:479)
 at com.android.packageinstaller.PackageInstallerActivity.$r8$lambda$RCIm8wl1VPqdfQgkgmrBIDbuvOQ(PackageInstallerActivity.java:0)
 at com.android.packageinstaller.PackageInstallerActivity$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.onClick(R8$$SyntheticClass:0)
 at com.android.packageinstaller.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:144)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
 at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:205)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8248)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
 at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:552)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:971)
```

One of the apps which can trigger this crash is "[Copy SMS Code - OTP Helper](https://f-droid.org/en/packages/io.github.jd1378.otphelper/)" (I use the F-Droid builds), the current version I have installed is 1.8.0 and all newer versions since (AFAIK) have exhibited this issue.

This is quite annoying because it is preventing updates to my apps.

Is there any way to fix this issue at all without waiting for Google to push an update? If not, where should I report this issue?

P.S. I just tried installing the same APK via ADB and it worked! So this is just a "Package Installer" app issue.

Comment: On an older Android 13 Pixel device the app installs fine via UI.

Comment: Based on a quick research, looks like this is a known issue of Android 14 QPR1: [Cromite GitHub Issue #595 - Crashes Package Installer on Android 14 QPR1](https://github.com/uazo/cromite/issues/595), [GrapheneOS Discussion Forum - java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not copy bitmap to parcel blob](https://discuss.grapheneos.org/d/9645-javalangruntimeexception-could-not-copy-bitmap-to-parcel-blob), [SyncThing GitHub Issue #2026 - Installing APK fails with 'java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not copy bitmap to parcel blob'](https://github.com/syncthing/syncthing-android/issues/2026)

Comment: @AndrewT. Those are similar complaints from other users, nothing upstream related. And QPR1 looks like one of those beta updates, and I have not opted into them, so I don't think this issue is limited to that release.

Comment: @Robert Yup, I never had this issue in Android 13 either, looks like it was introduced in 14. Someone needs to file a proper bug report and track down this issue.

Comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/303849830 marked resolved but still seems to be an issue